# Insert page break with Word

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have a VBScript that creates a big Word document. I need to have it insert a page break at the end so I can insert another select of text however I can't get the page break to work.

I've tried

```
objWord.Documents(tempFile).Activate
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.InsertBreak(7)
```

```
objWord.Documents(tempFile).Activate
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.InsertBreak(wdPageBreak)
```

```
objWord.Documents(tempFile).Activate
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.InsertBreak Type:=7
```

```
objWord.Documents(tempFile).Activate
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.InsertBreak Type:wdPageBreak
```

It just skips over it an inserts all the text without creating a page break.

Comment: VBScript or VBA? You've tagged both. They're not the same. Your title says VBA. Your first paragraph says VBScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using VBScript, since you're referencing Word using `objWord` instead of the `Application` object. I'm also assuming you have `On Error Resume Next` declared because you should be receiving an error trying to use some of those methods in VBScript. The `param:=value` syntax is not part of VBScript. Also, constants like `wdPageBreak` need to be explicitly declared in your script.

Since `wdPageBreak` is the default break type for `InsertBreak()`, you can just omit it completely. You may want to make sure you're truly at the end of your document, however. For that, you can use `Selection.EndKey()`, passing the value of `wdStory`. For example:

```
Const wdStory = 6

objWord.Selection.EndKey wdStory
objWord.Selection.InsertBreak       ' No param needed here
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to insert the page break. I'm putting your code in before I select from the other document and paste the text in

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a new page? Maybe you're just inserting your text at the wrong insertion point. Check your page count before and after running the code above.

Comment: Yeah still says page 3/3, it should insert the break on the 2nd page and put all the text on page 3 rather than half on 2 and half on 3. Ill if I still have 3 pages when I don't insert text at all

Comment: I'm confused. Did you have 3 pages before the code above executed or 2?

Comment: The paste I do after the page break code still ends up on the second page.

Comment: Ok, but are you getting an additional page using the code above? If so, we may just need to change your insertion point before you paste your text.

Comment: I moved the paste I was doing at now the page break works!